# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modeling'

Tags: python

I'm very new to deep learning and python and I'm trying to recreate the project at https://github.com/Nagakiran1/Extending-Google-BERT-as-Question-and-Answering-model-and-Chatbot

As I saw that in the project there is a file named `Bert_QuestionAnswer.ipynb` and with `data.txt` are the only difference I see from the original Bert repository, I just simply loaded it in my google drive and opened it as a notebook to see it in use.
When I run the first portion dough I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modeling'`errror.
What library is it part of? 
For somoebody this was the problem :

> It looks like it's trying to import from the github repo source rather
>   than the pip package.
>
> If you are running this in a directory that contains the BERT github
>   repo, try running it elsewhere.

As always many thanks for the help. 
This is the code of the file that throws me the error :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
import collections
import json
import math
import os
import random
import modeling
import optimization
import tokenization
import six
import os
import tensorflow as tf


import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').disabled = True
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")





import time
from pandas import Series
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import remove_stopwords
word_vectors = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100")  # load pre-trained word-vectors from gensim-data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell python where this module is:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/bert/repo")
```

Because python will search in his system folders and in the current working directory. If you don't run it in the repo, python doesn't find this module.

Comment: how do I link it to the repo? I guess I'm too new to all this..